# Redirect http page to another inside my computer?

Tags: internet

How can I automatically redirect a website to an html page inside my computer? I need to do this everytime I try to access the website in my ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Could describe more specific what you are trying to do? Are you administering the foreign website? What webserver is running?

Comment: Example, I could block yahoo editing the hosts. But how can I, instead of blocking it, redirect when someone tries to access it to a page with the info why that access couldn't be completed etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need a webserver running on localhost so that when your host's modification points, to use your example, yahoo.com to 127.0.0.1, it would query the local webserver which would show the page.

For a lightweight server, i'd recommend [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)